# what does "about 50%" mean?

Tags: meaning

I filed a VA claim for heart disease. My claim had a Ejection Fraction test which included the statement that my EF was "about 50%".  I filed a claim, as VA regulations state  EF  of 30-50% . The VA came back in letter and stated that about 50% can mean 50.1 or 50.01%  Websters has several different definitions, including about meaning almost. I have never heard of about 50% meaning MORE than 50% as the VA has stated.

Comment: It means it's ambiguous -- could be 48%, could be 52%.

Comment: "about" means approximately.  It could be more, it could be less.  The range (e.g. 40% to 60%) ideally should be made clear by the context, but it usually isn't.  Saying that "about 50%" means 50 to 50.1 percent is nonsense, but you need another test or a reinterpretation of your test, administered by a VA-savvy doc, or a  lawyer, not English wonks.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience ***[about](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about)*** means "within range of". It doesn't imply less than. M-W (linked) does seem to more-or-less agree with you.

If something is said to cost "about ten dollars" I would never assume that it could only be less than that.